# Why am I not able to add user input into database with front end as java and back end as mysql?

Tags: java, mysql, database

create table query for department :
create table department 
(
department_id tinyint(2) zerofill not null auto_increment,
department_name varchar(30) unique key,
department_description text,
primary key(department_id)
);

java code:
    package hrmps;

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import javax.swing.*;

class AddDepartment extends JPanel
{
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)
{                                         
String deptName=jTextField1.getText();
String deptDescription=jTextField2.getText();

Connection con=null;
PreparedStatement statement=null;
ResultSet rs=null;

String query="Insert into department values (?,?)";


             try
             {
                  Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
                con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql:///hrmps?               zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull","root","root");
                statement=con.prepareStatement(query);
                statement.setString(1,deptName);
                statement.setString(2,deptDescription);
                statement.execute();

                int i=statement.executeUpdate();

                if(i>0)

                     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Record added");


                else

                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Record couldn't     be added");


                con.close();
          }

        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
        }


}         //end of method
```

}//end of class

Comment: `isNullOrEmpty` actually returns `true` when the strings are NOT null or empty. Consider inverting your `return` statements.

Comment: @Berger is correct, if you switch the returns on the `isNullOrEmpty()` it will work. Just for future reference`if(boolean  == true)` can be reduced to `if(boolean)` no need to add in == true or false as you can use `if(!boolean)` when looking for a false value.

Comment: It still doesn't work :( even if I am deleting the whole isNullOrEmpty() method.

Comment: Remove the call to execute, and just use executeUpdate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
String deptName=jTextField1.getText();
String deptDescription=jTextField2.getText();
```

Those two statements are out of any method. So they're executed when the object is constructed, well before the user has any chance to type anything in the text fields.

Make those local variables of the `jButton1ActionPerformed` method. It's only when the button is clicked that you must read what the text fields contain.

BTW, all the fields in the posted code should be local variables. And your method `isNullOrEmpty` returns false when the argument is null or empty. That's very confusing.

Comment: Thank u for ur response. I have initialized all the variables in the constructor. It's just that I have posted only the important lines of the code. BTW, it still doesn't work even when I am completely erasing the isNullOrEmpty () method.

Comment: The fact that the two Strings are initialized in the constructor is precisely what causes the problem, as my answer explains. These two strings should not be instance fields. They should be **local** variables of jButton1ActionPerformed. And they should be initialized in jButton1ActionPerformed, when the button is clicked. Not in the constructor, when the UI is not even visible. Re-read the answer.

Comment: Sorry,but, I tried that as well and it still does not  add the data to the database  Can it be some syntax error in PreparedStatement?

Comment: How do you determine that? As said in the comments, just use executeUpdate(), not execute() then executeUpdate(). I guess the connection is in autocommit mode. Check it, and if it's not, call commit() before closing.

Comment: thank u very much. It finally works :) It seems there was a problem in the query passed. It should have been : String query="Insert into department (department_name,department_description) values (?,?)"; Once again, thank you :)